# How to compute the difference in monthly income for the same id

Tags: pandas, dataframe

The dataframe below shows the monthly revenue of two shops (`shop_id=11`, `shop_id=15`) during the period of a few years:

```
data = { 'shop_id' : [   11,    15,    15,    15,    11,   11 ],
         'month'   : [    1,     1,     2,     3,     2,    3 ],
         'year'    : [ 2011,  2015,  2015,  2015,  2014, 2014 ],
         'revenue' : [11000,  5000,  4500,  5500, 10000, 8000]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[['shop_id', 'month', 'year', 'revenue']]
display(df)
```

[image]

You can notice that `shop_id=11` has only one entry in 2011 (january) and `shop_id=15` has a few entries in 2015 (january, february, march). Nevertheless, it's interesting to note that the first shop has a few more entries in 2014:

[image]

I'm trying to optimize a custom function (used along with `.apply()`) that creates a new feature called `diff_revenue`: this feature shows the change in revenue from the previous month, for each shop:

[image]

I would like to offer some explanation on how some of the values found in `diff_revenue` were generated:

- The value first cell is **0** (red) because there is no previous information for `shop_id=11`;
- The 2nd cell is also **0** (orange), for the same reason: there is no previous information for `shop_id=15`;
- The 3rd cell is **500** (green), because the change from the last entry (january, 2015) of this shop to the current cell's revenue (february, 2015), is 500 Trumps.
- The 5th cell is **1000** (dark blue), because the change from the last entry (january, 2011) of this shop to the current cell's revenue (february, 2014) was 1000 Trumps.

I'm no expert in Pandas and was wondering if the Pandas' gods knew a better way. The DataFrame I have to work with is quite large (+1M observations) and my current approach is too slow. I'm looking for a faster alternative or maybe something more readable.

Comment: I gotta ask: "Trumps"?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Dollars = Trumps **;D**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You more or less want to use [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) on the `'Revenue'` column, but need to do a few additional things:

- Sort to ensure your DataFrame is in chronological order (can undo this later)
- Perform a `groupby` on `'shop_id'` to do group level operations
- Take the absolute value, since you don't want to distinguish between positive and negative

In terms of code:

```
# sort the values so they're in order when we perform a groupby
df = df.sort_values(by=['year', 'month'])

# perform a groupby on 'shop_id' and get the row-wise difference within each group
df['diff_revenue'] = df.groupby('shop_id')['revenue'].diff()

# fill NA as zero (no previous info), take absolute value, convert float -> int
df['diff_revenue'] = df['diff_revenue'].fillna(0).abs().astype('int')

# revert to original order
df = df.sort_index()
```

The resulting output:

```
   shop_id  month  year  revenue  diff_revenue
0       11      1  2011    11000             0
1       15      1  2015     5000             0
2       15      2  2015     4500           500
3       15      3  2015     5500          1000
4       11      2  2014    10000          1000
5       11      3  2014     8000          2000
```

**Edit**

A little less straight forward solution, but maybe slightly more performant:

```
# sort the values so they're chronological order by shop_id
df = df.sort_values(by=['shop_id', 'year', 'month'])

# take the row-wise difference ignoring changes in shop_id
df['diff_revenue'] = df['revenue'].diff()

# zero out locations where shop_id changes (no previous info)
df.loc[df['shop_id'] != df['shop_id'].shift(), 'diff_revenue'] = 0

# Take the absolute value, convert float -> int
df['diff_revenue'] = df['diff_revenue'].abs().astype('int')

# revert to original order
df = df.sort_index()
```